# make a JTextArea scrollable

Tags: java, scroll, jtextarea

How would I make the following `JTextArea` scrollable?

```
    private JTextArea getJTextArea1() {
    if (jTextArea1 == null) {
        jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
        jTextArea1.setBounds(new Rectangle(225, 162, 68, 29));
        jTextArea1.setText("text");
    }
    return jTextArea1;
}
```

Comment: JTextArea accepts ints to specify the number of rows and columns desired.  This is more robust than calling setBounds(), which is often ignored by layout managers, and will also work better in alternate PLAFs, different OS', fonts, screen sizes/resolutions..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a scrollpane:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Answer (score 0):

Some code:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```